# Error updating multiple rows on a table with triggers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, trigger, update

I have a Table Products with a Trigger to create a record on each update made to Products (something like a Log).

Everything works fine if I update one record at a time but if I try to update multiple records (Update Products SET Name = "BLABLABLA" WHERE Price > 10) I get the following error:

"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <=, >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. The statement has been terminated."

My Trigger is this one:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[NS_Art_Export_ProdUpdate] ON [dbo].[Produtos] FOR UPDATE
    AS BEGIN

    DECLARE @Key1 NVARCHAR(20), @Key2 NVARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @Changed BIT

    SET @Key1 = (SELECT Counter FROM INSERTED)
    SET @Key2 = (SELECT Prod_Gen FROM INSERTED)
    SET @Changed = 0

    IF UPDATE(Codigo) SET @Changed = 1
    IF UPDATE(NOME) SET @Changed = 1
    IF UPDATE(Familia) SET @Changed = 1
    IF UPDATE(CodIVA) SET @Changed = 1
    IF UPDATE(qtEmbal) SET @Changed = 1
    IF UPDATE(Volume) SET @Changed = 1
    IF UPDATE(PesoBrt) SET @Changed = 1
    IF UPDATE(PesoLiq) SET @Changed = 1
    IF UPDATE(Status) SET @Changed = 1

    IF @Changed = 1
        INSERT INTO Log_NSArtSoft 
            (Tabela,      Tipo,  Key1,   Key2,   Data_Update, 
             Data_Export, Flag_Update, Data_Export2) 
        VALUES 
            ('Produtos',  'U',   @Key1,  @Key2,  GETDATE(), 
             0, 0, 0)

END
GO
```

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: I added the [tag:sql-server] tag based on the `[dbo].` in your code. Please correct if that's not the case.

Comment: The problem is that you have set of rows in `INSERTED` table and you can't assign it to variable. You should follow this answer by @mehdi lotfi
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137102/sql-update-trigger-only-when-column-is-modified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that in SQL Server, Triggers fire once per *operation*, not once per *row*. So when you do multi-row operations, the subquery in `SET @Key1 = (SELECT Counter FROM INSERTED)` is returning a `Counter` value per each row updated. You need to restructure the `INSERT` as being a set-based operation as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[NS_Art_Export_ProdUpdate]
ON [dbo].[Produtos]
AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF (UPDATE(Codigo) OR UPDATE(NOME) OR UPDATE(Familia) OR
      UPDATE(CodIVA) OR UPDATE(qtEmbal) OR UPDATE(Volume) OR
     UPDATE(PesoBrt) OR UPDATE(PesoLiq) OR UPDATE([Status]))
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Log_NSArtSoft
            (Tabela, Tipo, Key1, Key2, Data_Update, Data_Export, Flag_Update, Data_Export2)
      SELECT 'Produtos', 'U', ins.[Counter], ins.[Prod_Gen], GETDATE(), 0, 0, 0
      FROM   INSERTED ins;
  END
END;
GO
```

Please keep in mind that the `UPDATE` function only indicates whether or not the column is in the `SET` clause of the `UPDATE` statement (in terms of an `AFTER UPDATE` Trigger; the `UPDATE` function returns **true** for all columns in the context of an `INSERT` operation). It does *not* indicate whether or not the value of that column has changed. Meaning, for the query of `UPDATE table SET ColA = ColA`, calling `UPDATE([ColA])` will return **true** even though the value is guaranteed to be the same.

Assuming that you do not want to log rows in which no values for the specified columns have changed, you need to JOIN the `inserted` and `deleted` tables and test each column between those two pseudo-tables. When testing the columns, you need to wrap NULLable columns in `ISNULL()`, and when the column is a string type (not `XML`) then you need to use a binary Collation to make sure that *all* changes get logged (even if they equate when linguistic rules are applied). Hence, the `SELECT` statement would change as follows (I have no idea what the datatype of any of the columns are, so the particular usage below for each one is purely for example):

```
  SELECT 'Produtos', 'U', ins.[Counter], ins.[Prod_Gen], GETDATE(), 0, 0, 0
  FROM   INSERTED ins
  INNER JOIN DELETED del
          ON del.[Key1] = ins.[Key1]
         AND del.[Key2] = ins.[Key2]
  WHERE  ins.Codigo <> del.Codigo -- NOT NULL number column
  OR     ISNULL(ins.[Status], -9999) <> ISNULL(del.[Status], -9999) -- NULLable number column
  OR     ISNULL(ins.PesoBrt, '1/1/1900') <> ISNULL(del.PesoBrt, '1/1/1900') -- NULLable date column
  OR     ins.NOME <> del.NOME COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 -- NOT NULL string column
  OR     ISNULL(ins.Familia, N'45#$%$%^$59jh35$%^$%~!@~!@#|{}\[]') <>
         ISNULL(del.Familia, N'45#$%$%^$59jh35$%^$%~!@~!@#|{}\[]')
         COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 -- NULLable string column
```

---

P.S. It is also a good idea to include `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the beginning of Triggers and Stored Procedures (unless a client application specifically needs that output, which is usually not the case).